# How do I use Application Loader to submit my app to the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, application-loader

How do I publish my app to the iOS app store using Application Loader? I don't know how to get the file for Application Loader to locate. Please tell me in easy steps. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of asking people here to post a long set of detailed instructions, why don't you find the instructions that Apple provides like everyone else does. This site should be the last place to seek help after you have made every effort to search for the relevant information first.

Answer (score 14):

Follow these steps:

1. In XCode, go to `Product > Archive` (*)
2. Click the <kbd>Distribute App</kbd> button, then select `App Store Connect > Export` and remember the export file location
3. In the menu go to `XCode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader`
4. Follow the steps, indicating the .ipa export file of step 2. That's it!

(*) if the `Archive` menu option is unavailable change device to "Generic iOS Device" in top left.

Answer (score 4):

Follow This Link

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

Install the certificate and go to projects build setting in Xcode. Find the “Code signing” section and set all items to “iPhone distribution: *your company name*”. Now choose “Archive” under product menu in Xcode.

Next log into iTunes connect and choose “Add new app” under My Applications. First create a new bundle (make sure that app identifiers match!) and then add the application.

Once you are done adding screenshots and general information, be sure to click “ready to add binary”. That’s all you need to do at iTunes connect.

Go back to xCode and open Organizer (Window – Organizer). Under archives tab you should see the archive for your application. Validate it and select Export to save your archive as .ipa file for App Store.

Next open Application loader (just search for it in spotlight). Choose “Deliver your app”. When prompted choose the previously created ipa file.

Answer (score 3):

Application Loader will not let you log in with your normal icloud password. Remember to generate an app-specific password for you.

1. Go to: https://appleid.apple.com/
2. Log in and go to Security.
3. Press Generate password
4. Use this password to log in to Application Loader.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397

Answer (score 2):

No need to use the Application Loader to submit your app to the App Store. In Xcode, make sure you've selected a physical device in the upper left corner, then from the menu, choose `Product`->`Archive`. After that's done, assuming no errors have occurred, the Organizer should pop up automatically and in the Archive tab, you can choose to submit your app to the App Store, by choosing `Distribute`.

Comment: Nope. Application Loader IS needed because often there's some kind of nonsense bug  in XCode that prevents the app of being uploaded. When that happens you just use Application Loader to succeed, that's the reason AL still exists. That's why I downvoted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

With xCode 11 the **Application Loader** was removed. 
https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/?id=submissionsupdate7-31

I found on an Adobe Forum:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/Animate/Xcode-11-don-t-have-application-loader/td-p/10516050

The suggestion was, use xcrun … on terminal; but it was not working for me :-(

```
xcrun altool --upload-app -f <file> -t <platform> -u <username> -p <password>
```

I installed parallel to xCode 11.1 xCode 10.3 and was able to use the `old Application Loader`

**Update 2019-11-27**:
Apple rolled-out the application 'Transporter', here the link to the [appstore](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784). The app is very similar to the "old" Application Loader and shows in case of errors speaking messages.

Answer (score 1):

Application Loader is no longer packaged with Xcode 11+. For a good automated tool, you can use the built-in command line tool, iTMSTransporter by running `xcrun iTMSTransporter`. More information [here](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdA3ae5a8b0?sub=apdA687d545d).