# How to to upload an ipa file to apple store on macOS High Sierra

Tags: ios, mobile, phonegap

I am new to mac os. I developed a mobile application with a tool called Devextreme. I was able to get and ipa file after registering for the google developer program .I was able to test on a single iphone using https://www.diawi.com/ to install the ipa.

Now, i got a macOS High Sierra version 10.13, Intel Core i5 . I want to upload my ipa file to apple store with my new mac device.

I tried to download xcode 11, but it says it is not compatible

How can i upload to apple store with the ipa file i have ?

Comment: Please see this answer 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36788022/5089923
,

You can use Application Loader

Comment: Upgrade your MacOS to `10.15.x` and then install new xcode 11.3 (stable)

Comment: k. Please while creating a certificate am i to to choose Apple Distribution  because for testing i selected apple development ? Can i build the ipa on windows as have done for the for testing the copy it to my mac and upload the ipa

Comment: you have to choose Apple distribution for App Store, can you install Xcode on windows?

Comment: No i can't, i have a new mac

Comment: Thanks. to you all . i have upgraded my mac os to catalina